# Catastrophic upgrade failure resulting in inability to install 'ubuntu-gnome-desktop' (crippled system)

Tags: gnome, upgrade, 18.04, 17.10

This has happened to me probably three times (on different systems) and I think it might have to do with a PPA that was active before the upgrade (**maybe Padoka**?). Every time my system has been beyond repair (by my abilities) and I've had to completely reinstall. This particular system configuration would make this a major undertaking that I would *really* **really** like to avoid if possible.

I initiated what should have been a simple upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04 which failed and left me with this:

```
:~$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-gnome-desktop is already the newest version (0.83).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-desktop : Depends: gdm3 but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gnome-settings-daemon but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gnome-shell but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ubuntu-session but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: deja-dup but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: gnome-calendar but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: gnome-getting-started-docs but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: gnome-initial-setup but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: gnome-todo but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-calc but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-gnome but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-impress but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-math but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-ogltrans but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-pdfimport but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-style-breeze but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-writer but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: nautilus-share but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: shotwell but it is not going to be installed
 ubuntu-gnome-desktop : Depends: gnome-session but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

---

```
:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-desktop:
 ubuntu-desktop depends on gdm3; however:
  Package gdm3 is not installed.
 ubuntu-desktop depends on gnome-control-center; however:
  Package gnome-control-center is not installed.
 ubuntu-desktop depends on gnome-settings-daemon; however:
  Package gnome-settings-daemon is not installed.
 ubuntu-desktop depends on gnome-shell; however:
  Package gnome-shell is not installed.
 ubuntu-desktop depends on ubuntu-session; however:
  Package ubuntu-session is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-gnome-desktop:
 ubuntu-gnome-desktop depends on ubuntu-desktop; however:
  Package ubuntu-desktop is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-gnome-desktop depends on gnome-session; however:
  Package gnome-session is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-gnome-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-desktop
 ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

---

```
:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bolt caribou gcc-7-base:i386 gdal-data gir1.2-mutter-1 gir1.2-nm-1.0 gir1.2-nma-1.0 gir1.2-tracker-2.0 gnome-todo-common kodi-bin libaec0 libarmadillo7
  libarmadillo8 libarpack2 libassimp3v5 libav-tools libavahi-compat-libdnssd1 libboost-random1.62.0 libbrotli1 libcdio15 libcec4 libcomerr2:i386
  libcrossguid0 libdap25 libdapclient6v5 libde265-0 libepsilon1 libfabric1 libfreerdp-cache1.1 libfreerdp-client1.1 libfreerdp-codec1.1
  libfreerdp-common1.1.0 libfreerdp-core1.1 libfreerdp-crypto1.1 libfreerdp-gdi1.1 libfreerdp-locale1.1 libfreerdp-plugins-standard
  libfreerdp-primitives1.1 libfreerdp-utils1.1 libfreexl1 libfyba0 libg15daemon-client1 libgdal20 libgeos-3.5.1 libgeos-3.6.2 libgeos-c1v5 libgeotiff2
  libgl2ps1 libgl2ps1.4 libglade2-0 libglvnd0 libgnome-todo libgraphene-1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgupnp-igd-1.0-4 libhdf4-0-alt libhdf5-100
  libhdf5-openmpi-100 libhwloc-plugins libhwloc5 libidn11-dev libjs-excanvas libkate1 libkeybinder0 libkmlbase1 libkmldom1 libkmlengine1 liblept5
  liblilv-0-0 libllvm5.0 libmicrohttpd10 libmjpegutils-2.1-0 libmpcdec6 libmpeg2encpp-2.1-0 libmplex2-2.1-0 libmutter-1-0 libnetcdf-c++4 libnetcdf11
  libnetcdf13 libnfs8 libnice10 libntfs-3g872 libodbc1 libofa0 libogdi3.2 libopencv-core3.1 libopencv-flann3.1 libopencv-imgproc3.1 libopencv-ml3.1
  libopencv-photo3.1 libopencv-shape3.1 libopencv-video3.1 libopencv-viz3.1 libopenmpi2 libp8-platform2 libpoppler68 libpq5 libproj12 libpsm-infinipath1
  libqhull7 libqt5concurrent5 libqt5positioning5 libqt5positioning5-plugins libqt5qml5 libqt5script5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite
  libqt5test5 libqt5webchannel5 libqt5webengine-data libqt5xml5 libre2-3 libre2-4 librtaudio5a librtmidi3 libserd-0-0 libshairplay0 libsodium18 libsord-0-0
  libsoundtouch1 libspandsp2 libspatialite7 libsratom-0-0 libsrtp0 libsrtp2-1 libsuperlu5 libsysmetrics1 libsz2 libtbb2 libtesseract-data libtesseract3
  libtinyxml2-5 libtinyxml2.6.2v5 liburiparser1 libvo-aacenc0 libvo-amrwbenc0 libvte-common libvte9 libvtk6.3 libvulkan1 libwildmidi-config libwildmidi2
  libwinpr-crt0.1 libwinpr-dsparse0.1 libwinpr-environment0.1 libwinpr-file0.1 libwinpr-handle0.1 libwinpr-heap0.1 libwinpr-input0.1
  libwinpr-interlocked0.1 libwinpr-library0.1 libwinpr-path0.1 libwinpr-pool0.1 libwinpr-registry0.1 libwinpr-rpc0.1 libwinpr-sspi0.1 libwinpr-synch0.1
  libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 libwinpr-thread0.1 libwinpr-utils0.1 libwoff1 libx264-148 libx265-130 libxcb-xinerama0 libxerces-c3.1 libxerces-c3.2 libzbar0
  linux-image-4.13.0-46-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-46-generic linux-signed-image-4.13.0-46-generic mkclean mkvalidator ocl-icd-libopencl1 odbcinst
  odbcinst1debian2 openmpi-bin openmpi-common proj-bin proj-data python-bluez python-gconf python-glade2 python-imaging python-keybinder python-notify
  python-olefile python-pil python-vte python3-sip qtbase5-dev-tools qtwebengine5-doc shotwell-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gnome-control-center gnome-settings-daemon
Suggested packages:
  rygel | rygel-tracker
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-gnome-desktop
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gnome-control-center gnome-settings-daemon
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 2 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1,942 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,094 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
```

---

```
:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]
Fetched 172 kB in 1s (303 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

---

```
:~$ apt-cache policy gdm3 ubuntu-gnome-desktop
gdm3:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.3
  Version table:
     3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
     3.28.2-0ubuntu1.4 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     3.28.0-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     3.26.1-3ubuntu3 -1
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
ubuntu-gnome-desktop:
  Installed: 0.83
  Candidate: 0.83
  Version table:
 *** 0.83 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

If I were to say `Y` to the `--fix-broken install`, I'd lose what little remains in this broken state. I'm at a complete loss as to what to do to fix this and I'm afraid to try anything for fear of making the problem worse (which is what usually happens).

Please help!

Comment: Possibly you have something wrong with your sources.  If you run `apt-cache policy gdm3 ubuntu-gnome-desktop` what do you get?  (add the output to your question).   Also check you have 'universe' enabled (ubuntu-gnome-desktop is in universe - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ubuntu-gnome-desktop)

Comment: @guiverc updated - I believe I do have `universe` enabled: `deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main universe restricted multiverse` (`/etc/apt/sources.list`)